# JavaScript UIEvents being blocked by synchronous debug code

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, event-handling

I was debugging some blur/click event handling and discovered that using breakpoints or alert popups to debug event handling can block other events from being handled. I've provided a jsfiddle with 2 input fields. One input field has a blur() event handler that alerts when called. If you click the input field to gain focus, and then click the button, the button will trigger an alert popup UNLESS the input field you chose has the blur() handler. The action of the blur handler seems to stop the click() handler from even happening.

I have discovered that the same thing occurs when using breakpoints. Using breakpoints in place of the alerts has the same effect. Breaking in the middle of the blur() will prevent the click() handler from even being called.

Is something going terribly wrong? What would be a good way to stop this from happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/stconrad/vtka7tt3/

```
$(".text").blur(function(e){
    var x = 0;
});

$(".text2").blur(function(e){
    alert("blurred")
});

$("button").click(function(){
   alert("clicked"); 
});
```

Comment: If `debugger;` breakpoints don't work you'll have to go back to `console.log` debugging. Never use `alert`.

Comment: i agree with Bergi's comment above, also u can use fire bug while using firefox browser

Comment: I've been using chrome developer console. I guess I came here because I was surprised that one breakpoint would cause another breakpoint in an async thread to be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to `alert()` method. When you are calling this method, only a single alert can be displayed at once. Then, here, two alerts are triggered in the same time (almost). Unfortunately, second one is simply ignored.

If you test with `console.log()`, you can see there are two outcomes in your debugger.

What you can do is to use a FIFO to handle your triggers. Simply append your call to the structure and pop first item. If there is a single call, it will be identical to your current process. Otherwise, first one will be triggered, then other one.

If you are using actions such as `alert()` which are blocking operations, use callbacks to trigger next operation: when alert is done, pop next item if there are some.